# regular expression allowing only english alphanumeric and "-"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression that allows english alphabets and numbers and "-" and not allow every thing else.
 but recently I found out that my regular expression not stopping french language alphabets and numbers

My regular expression is as follow,

```
@"[^\w\d-]";
```

How can I change the above regular expression so only english alphabets, numbers and "-" can be allowed only?

Comment: FYI that would also allow `_`

Comment: Try this A-Za-z  And I think you need the - as a - to be first

Comment: Move the caret outside square brackets.

Comment: See duplicate, replace underscore (`_`) with dash (`-`).

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change the above regular expression so only english alphabets, numbers and "-" can be allowed only?

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$"
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start. `$` Asserts that we are at the end. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.